# Android Exception while parsing JSON URL

Tags: android, json, android-activity, mobile, gson

I'm trying to parse a JSON response from a URL and populate it to an array. I get this Exception when trying to parse my json response URL:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Here's what my response looks like:

```
{"firstName":"Roger","lastName":"Davis","email":"rog@gmail.com","password":"test123","profilePicture":"googleimagesblablabla","settings":[]}
```

My Code:

```
            URL url = new URL(myurl);
            HttpURLConnection urlRequest = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlRequest.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlRequest.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlRequest.addRequestProperty("ACCEPT", "application/json");
            urlRequest.addRequestProperty("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", mobileServiceAppId);
            urlRequest.addRequestProperty("email",email);
            urlRequest.addRequestProperty("password",pass);

            JSONObject[] response = null;

        try {

                // Prepare some objects to receive the bytes of data
                // from the Azure Mobile Service
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                        urlRequest.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));

                // responseString will hold our JSON data
                StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                // Loop through the buffered input, reading JSON data
                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    responseString.append(line);
                }

                // Convert responseString into a JSONArray
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonArray.length(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("ERROR",obj.getString("lastName"));
                }


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("ERROR", ex.toString());
            }
```

Am I parsing the values wrong from the response? How can I fix this, folks?

Comment: Use JSONObject instead JSONArray and parse values one by one "remove for loop".

Comment: i have added my answer for your query check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well actually your json response does not have any array in it :

```
{"firstName":"Roger","lastName":"Davis","email":"rog@gmail.com","password":"test123","profilePicture":"googleimagesblablabla"}
```

it has all object in the response you can parse your response from the below given code snippet.

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());
String firstName = reader.getString("firstName");
String lastName= reader.getString("lastName");
String email= reader.getString("email");
String password= reader.getString("password");
String profilePicture= reader.getString("profilePicture");
```

and remove this part from your code :

```
 // Convert responseString into a JSONArray
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseString.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),jsonArray.length(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("ERROR",obj.getString("lastName"));
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON Array, JSON array starts with '[' and ends with ']'

`{"firstName":"Roger","lastName":"Davis","email":"rog@gmail.com","password":"test123","profilePicture":"googleimagesblablabla"}`

So you should use `JSONObject` instead

Comment: I do have an array in the response. However it could be null sometimes

Comment: Now I'm getting this: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(responseString.toString());
String firstName = reader.getString("firstName");
String lastName= reader.getString("lastName");
String email= reader.getString("email");
String password= reader.getString("password");
String profilePicture= reader.getString("profilePicture");

Comment: It seems that your response contains not only the JSON Object, perhaps you can post the full http response